# Align Tab Item and Tab Control Border in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I Have the XAML below:

```
<Page
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
```

```
<TabControl Margin="10" TabStripPlacement="Left" BorderBrush="gray">
<TabControl.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="TabItem">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
    <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="gray" />
    <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="lightgray" />
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
          <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="6,0,0,6" />
          <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,1.5" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
  </Style>      
</TabControl.Resources>
  <TabItem Header="Tab 1">
    Conten1
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem Header="Tab 2">
    Content2
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem Header="Tab 3">
    Content2
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>

</Border>
```

What do I need to change in the xaml above such that TabItem top and bottom borders are aligned with the tab control border?
I want it to look as if top tab item control and top tabcontrol border form a single line. Same with bottom border.

Answer (score 0):

try the below code. There are few changes. Hope it helps.

```
<TabControl Margin="10" TabStripPlacement="Left" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" BorderBrush="gray">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">

                <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="gray" />
                <Setter Property="Border.Background" Value="lightgray" />
                <Style.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="6,0,0,6" />
                        <!--<Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,1.5" />-->
                    </Style>
                </Style.Resources>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            Conten1
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            Content2
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Header="Tab 3" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            Content2
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
```